How to create Hnmr graphs in asymptote
I was wondering how to form peaks like these in an asymptote graph

Currently I only know how to do one peak, which I did using Bezier curves as follows:
real width = 0.008;
real spikeshift0 = 4;
real height1 = 2;
guide spike1 = (spikeshift0 - width, 0.25) 
              .. controls (spikeshift0 - width + 0.005, 0.5) and (spikeshift0 - width + 0.01, height1 - 0.05) 
              .. (spikeshift0 + width - 0.01, height1 - 0.05) 
              .. controls (spikeshift0 + width - 0.005, 0.5) and (spikeshift0 + width, 0.25) 
              .. (4 + width, 0.25);
draw(spike1);

This creates the following output

I'm not sure how to transform this into two, or multiple spikes melded together. There's only a minor aesthetic difference (that I don't mind leaving if it's too hard to fix) but my spikes go up sharply from the baseline while the example curve bends upwards smoothly. Could someone provide a general guidance on how I could draw a doublet, triplet and so on? I'm especially focussed on having symmetrical spikes where the middle spike is the longest and each spike to the left and right get successively shorter.  Does my current approach using Bezier curves work in this respect? Thank you for any insights :)

I am unsure what you try to achieve, but isn't this essentially all about chosing the right coordinates? I am unsure how the final curve should look like exactly since I don't know its function or specifics, but maybe something like this can serve as starting point:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(4cm);
path spike1 = (0, 0) 
    .. (2, 0)
    .. controls (2.75, 0) and (3, 0.25) 
    .. (3, 1)
    -- (3.25, 25)
    -- (3.5, 1)
    -- (3.75, 23)
    -- (4, 1)
    .. controls (4, 0.25) and (4.25, 0) 
    .. (5.25, 0)
    -- (20, 0);
draw(spike1);
\end{asy}
\end{document}



Thank you very much, your point placement got me kickstarted on a much more fruitful track ^^

@PenandPaper That was my intention :)
